# Need to know how to Integrate Gazebo with Python code

Tags: python, ros, gazebo-simu

Suppose I have a Python code for the A* algorithm, and I would like to create an environment in the Gazebo simulator with a starting and goal point. In this environment, a robot must move from the start to the goal position, using the A* algorithm to decide which action to take. The robot's actions are up, down, left, and right.

What are the step-by-step operations I need to perform to complete this project? I have the general idea, but I am unsure where to start or which topics to focus on. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple answers to this question, but here is one:

- Start with the configuration space, think what the configuration of your robot is. Learn about the configuration obstacle space, configuration free space etc.
- Use a space decomposition algorithm in the configuration space. Examples: fixed-size cell decomposition, adaptive-size cell decomposition etc.

  - These algorithms will generate a discrete graph of the configuration free space.
- Use A* to search that graph (there should be a node in that graph that corresponds to the start, and A* will search for a path from start to goal).
- The solution will be a sequence of configurations that your robot need to move through (from start to goal). That's not still a solution.
- Implement the control algorithm to move the robot from configuration to configuration.